# Why is TextInfo.ListSeparator returned as a string?

Tags: c#, globalization

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it if it has.

I am currently refactoring some code and removing the hard coded list seperator that I am splitting stuff with.

I am replacing it with TextInfo.ListSeparator from the `System.Globalization` namespace and noticed that it returns a string rather than a char.

Are there any cultures where more than a single character is used as a list seperator? Or is it completely safe to do something like this:

```
 line.Split(culture.TextInfo.ListSeparator.First());
```

Assuming that it will only ever return a string that is one character in length.

Comment: There might be some cultures that use a multiple-character list separator, but in the general case, this setting is customizable by the user anyway. Anyone can configure his system so it uses multiple-character list separators, regardless of the culture.

Comment: There does not appear to be any cultures where the list separator is not 1 character `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Where(c => c.TextInfo.ListSeparator.Length != 1)` however it is possible someone could create their own culture that does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not avoid the assumption and use something like

```
line.Split(new string[] {culture.TextInfo.ListSeparator}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Interesting, I will give this a go and let you know how it goes. Cheers.